# Why is this portion of code still executing?

Tags: c++, c

Why is my else, cout << "You have entered an incorrect code" still executing and writing to the screen after I enter r or R and complete the calculation and dialogue. The same does not happen when I enter p or P and follow through with that portion of my program. Sorry for the incredibly nooby question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char service;
    int number;
    int minutes;
    int dayMinutes;
    int nightMinutes;
    double bill;
    double dayCharge;
    double nightCharge;
    double const REG_FEE = 10.00;
    double const PREM_FEE = 25.00;
    double const REG_MIN = 0.20;
    double const PREM_DAY = 0.10;
    double const PREM_NIGHT = 0.05;

    cout << "Please enter your account number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Please enter your service type (regular or premium): ";
    cin >> service;

    if (service == 'r' || service == 'R')
{
        cout << "How many minutes have been used for this service?: ";
        cin >> minutes;

        if (minutes <= 50)
        {
            bill = REG_FEE;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
            cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
            cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
            cout << "You used: " << minutes << " minutes." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            bill = ((minutes - 50) * REG_MIN) + REG_FEE;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
            cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
            cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
            cout << "You used: " << minutes << " minutes." << endl;
        }

}
    if (service == 'p' || service == 'P')
{
        cout << "How many minutes were used during the day?: ";
        cin >> dayMinutes;
        cout << "How many minutes were used during the night?: ";
        cin >> nightMinutes;

        if (dayMinutes > 75)
        {
            dayCharge = ((dayMinutes - 75) * PREM_DAY);
        }
        if (nightMinutes > 100)
        {
            nightCharge = ((nightMinutes - 100) * PREM_NIGHT);
        }
            bill = dayCharge + nightCharge + PREM_FEE;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
            cout << "Your bill is $" << bill << "." << endl;
            cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
            cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
            cout << "You used: " << dayMinutes + nightMinutes << " minutes." << endl;

}
    else
    {
            cout << "You have entered an invalid service code." << endl;
            cout << "The account number entered was: " << number << "." << endl;
            cout << "The service type entered was: " << service << "." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because if you enter `R` or `r`, you do not enter `p` and the `else` is executed of the `if (service == 'p' || service == 'P')` statement.

Comment: @Therkel: y u write answer in comments

Comment: If run this code in "c" it will failed.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I was afraid such small response would not be considered a proper answer. I see it has been posted as an answer since, though.

Comment: @Therkel: The comment section is for requesting clarification not giving mini-answers (which, in comment form, cannot be upvoted/downvoted/reviewed/edited in the same way and are thus not subject to the same oversight that real answers are, which is a problem!) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need this-

```
 if (service == 'r' || service == 'R'){
  // your code
 }
 else if(service == 'p' || service == 'P'){
  //your code
 }
 else {
  //your code 
 }
```

Problem right now with your code is that if you even enter `'r'` or `'R'`,  due to `if else` condition with `'p'` or `'P'` becomes `false` and `else` part gets executed .

That's why you needed to use `if - else if` format so that for an input only one part is executed.